# SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface not working

Tags: textures, sdl2

Code:

```
SDL_Surface* tmpSurface = IMG_Load("Assets/Player.png");
playerTex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, tmpSurface);
SDL_FreeSurface(tmpSurface);
```

Rendering the Texture:

```
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, playerTex, NULL, NULL);
```

I did check to see if any of them returned null and playerTex is still null even though it is being set to a texture, im not sure why can anyone help

Comment: What does `SDL_GetError()` say?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this: I was creating a new renderer when I was initializing the texture instead of reusing the public one.

Using `SDL_GetError` helped me figure this out.

Comment: You might want to consider marking this as the accepted answer if it solves the issue.